# I want to disable isort imports error in python projects

Tags: python, isort

Imports are incorrectly sorted and/or formatted.isort(E)
[image]

Comment: This is up to the configuration of your editor/IDE.

Comment: so how to correct this

Comment: Learn how to configure your IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Visual Studio Code, then click the extensions panel on the far left (or just use Ctrl+Shift+X). Find the "isort" extension, right click it, and select "disable".